How to recompile vba project programmatically?
I am using a lot of Excel enabled macros (.xlsm) format, there are a lot of formulas and vba code in each file.  The problem is sometimes the .xlsm will randomly throw error such as the following:

Can't find Library or project
Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type
When you open the .xlsm file, it will just close by itself even when you are doing nothing.

All of these problems can be solved by opening the Excel file (.xlsm) with macros disabled at default, then goto developer tab, then save the file.  Then close the file, the next time you open the file, the file will be fixed.  I think by doing this you are actually recompiling all the vba libraries and vba codes.  I can do this manually but sometimes when we have a lot of files with this kind of problem, it is time consuming.  Anybody can suggest vba source code to fix the problem.
P.S.: I can now open the Excel file by disabling the macros by default at the start, the only thing I don't know how to do is how to compile the vba project of the file using vba programmatically.
Here is my existing code:
Sub Fix_XLMS_File()
     Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
            
     Set wbUpdate = Workbooks.Open("c:\vba\sample.xlsm")

     ' Thinking of inserting here the code to compile the code/library to fix this file.

     Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow

     wbUpdate.Close True
End Sub

Thank you.

possibly ... automate compile function of MS Office's VBA code ?
